# example of a good software design document

Tags: documentation, personas

Anyone got any online examples of good software design documents.  I want personas, goals, scenarios and all that good stuff.

I wish Cooper would have included a document with his books.

Comment: You can find some templates and documents at [usability.gov](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/resources/templates.html)

Answer (score 8):

Not exactyly an example, but how can I forego the chance to mention the four part series on functional design by our StackExchange founding partner Joel that inspired all subsequent design documents I created:

- Painless Functional Specifications - Part 1: Why Bother? http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html
- Painless Functional Specifications - Part 2: What's a Spec? http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000035.html
- Painless Functional Specifications - Part 3: But... How? http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000034.html
- Painless Functional Specifications - Part 4: Tips http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000033.html

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the documentation framework unify from eightshapes http://unify.eightshapes.com/, it provides indesign components and templates to allow you to create compelling design documents that you list.

For guidance upon the content of Personas Forrester have an up to date paper that compares personas from a number of well known digital agencies.

Comment: That is a dead link for me :'(

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a number of resources:

- [Design for Software: A Playbook for Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/111994290X) by Erik Klimczak.
- [Google's Material Design Documentation](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html#)
- [Microsoft's User Interface Principles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728831(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Kirigami Human Interface Guidelines](https://community.kde.org/KDE_Visual_Design_Group/KirigamiHIG)
- [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/)